# Strange behavior with created date

Tags: datetime, timezone, plone

I have something strange with time of created objects.

I'm in france, and the server time is ok.

When I create a new document at 09:45, I have thoses data in the catalog :

```
Date                2012-07-13T07:45:01+00:00 
ModificationDate    2012-07-13T07:45:01+00:00 
created             2012/07/13 05:44:37.933325 GMT 
modified            2012/07/13 05:45:1.990650 GMT 
CreationDate        2012-07-13T07:44:37+00:00
```

created and modified are 4 hours before !

Is there a way to fix the timezone or something to correct that ?

Comment: How did you display these dates? The Plone methods of converting catalog-stored dates are rather naive when it comes to timezones, but the stored data is still consistent.

Comment: I've got thoses dates from the portal_catalog in the ZMI, clicked on the object and see that.

Comment: My guess is that the timezone gets mangled in some point, badly. Is your server clock in UTC time or local time? How is the timezone set for Zope (or Python process generally)? It looks like the server time would be in a local time +2 hours instead of UTC time, but the assumption made about the local clock is wrong and Plone thinks it is UTC time. Or something along the lines :(

Comment: The server is in local time (UTC+2), and the timezone for zope is the one by default, I haven't configured anything for this...